# Shouldn't time pass slower and slower for an object under gravity according to the equivalence principle?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, equivalence-principle

According to the theory of special relativity time is relative and passes slower the faster you move.
According to the equivalence principle gravitational and inertial forces are of a similar nature and often indistinguishable.

So when you accelerate uniformly time should pass slower and slower.
So I wonder if the same effect should happen under gravity.

Does time pass slower and slower under gravity?

Comment: The time an observer measures on his own clock always passes at the same right, both in SR and GR. But you seem to be asking about gravitational time dilation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation which has been asked lots here.

Comment: I am asking if time passes slower and slower in an accelerating rocket. And if so, shouldn't it pass slower and slower under gravity ?